# Netbook edition 10.04 default mail client

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook, indicator, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add Mozilla Thunderbird to the messaging menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442/is-there-a-way-to-add-mozilla-thunderbird-to-the-messaging-menu)

I've installed the Netbook edition 10.04, and I've setted Thunderbid as default mail program, but when I click on the mail icon in the tray bar, it always calls Evolution...

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/223374/) to let Thunderbird work with the Ubuntu Mail Indicator (aka the envelop icon on the taskbar). Install it in Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to integrate Thunderbird into the indicator applets is detailed in this post by OMG Ubuntu : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/thunderbird-ubuntu-notification-applet/

Direct Link : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/223374/

Comment: Sorry - same info as Javier posted!

Comment: This might also be of interest if you prefer not to have Thunderbird running but still need indicator-based notification of new -email : https://launchpad.net/popper