# Removing Evolution Mail related options on top-panel

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove “Set Up Mail” from message indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-from-message-indicator)

I would like to remove all the mail-related options from the top panel while keeping the chat and broadcast options on the Unity top panel.

How can I do this?

Comment: People have asked this before.  Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-from-message-indicator/7855#7855).

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get remove evolution-indicator that will do it

Answer (score 1):

To just disable the evolution indicator: Evolution -> Edit -> Plugins an uncheck Evolution Indicator.