# How can I remove the Evolution package completely?

Tags: package-management, evolution

how can I remove Evolution and all related packages? I feel like I don't need them.

Comment: This could help: [Is there a usage count for packages or programs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118886/is-there-a-usage-count-for-packages-or-programs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from a terminal window give the following command to remove evolution completely

```
sudo apt-get purge evolution
```

After this re-validate using `dpkg -l|grep -i evolution` and remove any other evolution related packages using same command as above.

Comment: Just don't remove evolution-data-server and friends...

Comment: @ali1234 What happens when you remove `evolution-data-server` and friends..?

Comment: It's a dependency of gnome-panel, which in turn is a dependency of quite a lot of gnome stuff. Removing it will remove half your desktop along with it.

Comment: @ali1234 I hate evolution. It is like microsoft outlook. Overloaded and only needed in business desktop my opinion

Comment: Do you discard evolution dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

Open  System -> Administration -> Synaptic Package Manager

Search For Evolution and mark them for complete removal

[image]

Now Apply the changes .

[image]

Now a new window will open and click apply again .

[image]

Evolution will be removed.

Comment: Thanks. Easy solution but not very clean. Some libraries not removed from my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on Jamess's answer: For my Ubuntu 13.04, purging the following packages removes evolution and all of its dependencies:

```
apt-get purge evolution-common libevolution
```

As noted before, don't remove `evolution-data-server` and friends.

Answer (score 1):

I tried twice to remove Evolution following the advise above. The result was that the panels disappeared. The system was Ubuntu 11.04.

The only way I have found so far is to run `sudo apt-get install unity-2d`. This returns the panels and the functionality of Ubuntu. And yes, Evolution has disappeared. Unity-2d returns the icons, I have just managed to get rid of the indicator. It seems that the panels are connected to Evolution somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running gnome-classic on 12.10. When I uninstalled evolution it also uninstalled `evolution-common` and `gnome` - this last made me nervous but in fact things work fine after - and after login the desktop is ready in a fraction of the time it used to be. (oh and I suggest removing zeitgeist also if you don't use the desktop search features - this also slows things down at login).