# Isn't the calendar applet supposed to show today's date under the clock?

Tags: applet, calendar

I haven't used my computer for weeks, so I'm asking here before I report a bug.

If I click on the clock, it shows yesterday's date above the calendar, but highlight's today's date.

[image: Here's what I'm seeing on June 1]

Did I do something nuts to make that happen? (Using a clean install of Natty and Unity.)

Comment: Doesn't do that for me. Running fully updated Natty.

Comment: I don't have that problem either. Does it persist if you log out and log in again?

Comment: It's correct now. I'll have to check if it happens again tomorrow morning. Could be a timezone craziness?

Comment: @Florian: I doesn't persist if I logout and login.

Comment: Closed as Offtopic: Bug Reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/799465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that it's a bug. I've [reported it here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/799465).

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using Evolution and put in events which you didn't finish? Because if I click on that wrong date, it goes to Evolution Setup Assistant (I didn't set Evolution up, I'm using web-mail).

What an other probability is for the issue is that the date in Evolution isn't set up properly, but that seems very unlikely to me.

Finally it might be an anomaly, meaning just a weird glitch. I hope any of these suggestions is any help for you.

Comment: No, I don't use Evolution. In fact, I completely removed evolution with [steps from this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32231/how-can-i-remove-the-evolution-package-completely/32234#32234). Maybe that's related?

Comment: Actually, I didn't I just removed `evolution`, but apparently not all of the packages with `evolution` in their name. Regardless, I'm not using evolution.