# How do I add (mail) programs to the messages indicator?

Tags: launcher, indicator, google, gmail

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 with unity, i just wonder why gnome-default-applications-properties only show me the evolution program. There was no customize option before?

Just would like to launch Google email from the messages indicator.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gmail Notifier](https://launchpad.net/gm-notify) program integrates with the mail indicator very nicely. You can install through this command :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gm-notify
```

The open the `gm-notify` program to choose your settings. If you want to remove the evolution icon from the menu, please see [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-from-message-indicator)

Comment: Thanks for your help. but this repository didnt seem to work for me. Where i can find some info?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I totally forgot to add the link. It's there now. Hopefully you can successfully add the ppa.

Comment: Oh excellent, they finally include it into the Universe Repository, just do a sudo apt-get install gm-notify and it install it ! thanks