# Remove entries from messaging menu

Tags: 11.10, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove “Set Up Mail” and other entries from the message indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-and-other-entries-from-the-message-indicator)

In Ubuntu 11.10, how do I remove the *Chat*, *Broadcast* and *Set Up Mail...* entries from the messaging menu?

I tried blacklisting them by symlinking (say, `~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/empathy` to `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/empathy`) but that didn't do anything...

Has the blacklisting method changed? Do I have to use other application names?

Comment: @nitstorm I'm not so sure, since that question seems specific to an older version of Ubuntu using Evolution. 11.10 now comes with Thunderbird by default. Also, note that the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-from-message-indicator/7851#7851) there did not work for this asker.

Comment: @jfoucher: Have you tried just removing the applications from `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/`? @Warriorking64: Thought the accepted answer in the linked question asked the user to remove the file from the above directory

Comment: @nitstorm On a second look, you're right about the answer. I must've just misread something.

Comment: What does running `cp /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/* ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist/` do? For me it removes all the items except *Chat*.

Comment: Yes @Dor, that did the trick for everything except chat. The symlink method seems not to work anymore. And the _Chat_ item is still here...