# How do I/is it possible to remove the Broadcast option from the messaging indicator?

Tags: indicator, gwibber, messaging-menu

I would like to remove an applet from the GNOME panel/indicator applet (the Gwibber/broadcasting applet, to be precise) in Unity mode.

Is this possible?

If so, would any techniques also apply to other applets that other programs may place there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I did was create the folder `~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist`.  Then inside it, I created a text file called `gwibber.indicator` with only one line:

```
/usr/share/applications/gwibber.desktop
```

Now log out and back in (or kill and restart the panel) and you should see the broadcast item is gone.

The authoritative source for this is [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu#API).  It explains how to blacklist items on the messaging menu by using the above procedure.  One thing that is perhaps not explained is how to find the right name to use for the text file (why gwibber.indicator instead of just gwibber for example) and how to find the path to the desktop file.

To find the name, you can simply `ls /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications`.  The desktop path should be like the one for the gwibber example above, but you can `ls /usr/share/applications/` to check it's there.

To *add* your own application to the messaging menu, you need to create a folder:

```
mkdir ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications
```

Then put a text file with the a path to the application's desktop file; I think you can pick any name here.

References:

- [How can I remove "Set Up Mail" and other entries from the message indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-from-message-indicator)

Comment: Perfect!  It worked like a charm!  However, I would like to know if this applies to other applets and if so, how I would find the name of them so that I can add them to the blacklist.

Comment: @grant-veseley Hi Grant.  I've been busy, dealing with my own Ubuntu issues among other things :)  I've updated my answer to hopefully answer your questions.

Comment: I followed this instructions for removing the Broadcast option, and they were only gone for like a minute after I logged back in.  Then they reappeared again.  I've opened another question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436283/remove-options-from-messaging-indicators),