# How can i remove entries from the messaging menu in 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove “Set Up Mail” and other entries from the message indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-and-other-entries-from-the-message-indicator)

In previous Ubuntu versions i could add a .desktop file in `~/.config/applications/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist` and the items would no longer appear in the messaging menu. In 12.10 this no longer works. How can i remove unwanted entries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

#### For 12.10 and newer:

Go to `dconf-editor` and then `canonical > indicator > messages` and remove the app you don't want to see.