# Thunderbird is preferred mail app, messaging menu still loads evolution

Tags: thunderbird, messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add Mozilla Thunderbird to the messaging menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442/is-there-a-way-to-add-mozilla-thunderbird-to-the-messaging-menu)

Hi,

After installing ubuntu I setup my email in evolution, which is fine but on balance I prefer Thunderbird so I installed and set that up.

Under preferred applications I have set the mail to Thunderbird, but when I click on the icon in the top right (the mail envelope) and select mail it still loads evolution.

Is there a way to switch this to Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/indicators-for-thunderb-223374/) that let's Thunderbird use the message indicator in Ubuntu:

[image]

But it will not delete the evolution entry, to do that you need to remove `/usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution`

Related: [How can I remove "Set Up Mail" and other entries from the message indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7850/remove-set-up-mail-from-message-indicator)